# Why is jar ignoring my manifest?

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I tried to create an executable jar using this command:

```
jar -cvfm h.jar Manifest.mf Whatever1.class Whatever2.class
```

The manifest contains this:

```
Main-Class: Whatever1
```

But if I try to run the jar, I get: `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from my.jar`. I extracted the jar, and I saw that the contents of it's manifest were this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

Why was my manifest ignored?

EDIT: I know that using the `-e` flag I can specify an entry point, and jar will generate a correct manifest, but I'd like to know how to make this version work.

Comment: Try http://java.sys-con.com/node/36995

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a line break after the last line of `Manifest.mf`

Comment: saved my day. took me an hour of messing around until I found your answer.

Comment: was getting frustrated until i saw your post

Comment: This saved me much time...afraid...i saw this post little late...after spending a day on this...but thanks anyways !!!

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that not having a newline at the end of the manifest file causes this problem at times.  See if adding a new line at the end of the manifest file helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to run jar like:

`jar -cvf h.jar -m Manifest.mf Whatever1.class Whatever2.class`

Because values for options come directly after the option itself.

Comment: This says: `-m : no such file or directory`.

Comment: It needs to be `jar -cmvf h.jar Manifest.mf Whatever1.class Whatever2.class`