# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Generating Executable Jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I have created my JAR on Windows 2000 having java version 1.5 which contains following directories/files:

- manifest.txt
- com
- lib

**lib** contains all JARS which I want to make part of my JAR. **com** contains my class files and below is manfiest.txt file

```
Main-Class: com.as.qst.result.ResultTriggerSchedular 
Class-Path: lib/axis.jar lib/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar lib/jaxrpc.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/medplus-hub-8.2-wsclients.jar lib/medplus-hub-13.1-jaxws-clients.jar lib/quartz-2.2.1.jar lib/quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar lib/saaj.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar lib/ wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar lib/xercesImpl.jar com\as\qst\result
```

I used following command to generate my JAR

```
  jar cvfm test.jar manifest.txt com lib
```

It has successfully created a JAR file but when I try to run it with

```
java -jar test.jar
```

it does not execute and throws above exception. I used the same process for Windows 7 which has version 1.7 and it did work out even without class files path in manifest.txt `com\as\qst\result`. Is something more to do with class-path besides defining in manifest? and why is it working in Windows 7?

Comment: where is the exception trace?

Comment: It throws exception as `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ad/qst/result/ResultTriggerScehdular`, nothing else

Comment: Did you copy and paste that or retype it? Because it has multiple typos.

Comment: Can you try "./" before lib and let us know if that works

Comment: sure but it is even unable to find my main class...

Comment: Shouldn't be the file called MANIFEST.MF, all uppercase, and this file should be stored inside META-INF folder inside your jar?

Comment: @Hirak it didn't work.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza when I opened my jar this hierarchy of manifest file was created by tool.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the class file path in your class path entry. So instead of adding `com\as\qst\result` to your `class-path`.

More over you must not package other jar files in your runnable jar.

Other required jars must be provided in the same folder as your jar file (may be in separate folder) and Add current directory "." (without quotes) to your `class-path`.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Just found this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518957/noclassdeffounderror-with-executable-jar). This might give you more insight. Please read through it.

Comment: I did change my class-path to add `./` to all jars and not package these jars to my jar. but it still gives same exception. I read link too which says that when main class name in manifest was completed, at least tool was able to find main class which is not happening in my case. It will read others jar after finding my main class.

Comment: did you add current directory to your class-path?